# XAMLのStyle.Triggersで複合条件を指定したい

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPFでラジオボタンのユーザーコントロールを作っています。
このラジオボタンの外見を、`IsChecked`と`IsEnabled`の値に応じて変えたいです。
どちらも`bool`なので、合計で4種類の外見(`DataTemplate`)を定義することになると思います。

下記のコードのように、`IsChecked`のみであれば、`Style.Triggers`によって条件を指定し、適用する`DataTemplate`を切り替えることができることは分かっています。
しかし、`IsChecked`と`IsEnabled`の両方を見て切り替える方法が分かりません。

```
<!-- 4種類の外見に対応するDataTemplateを定義 -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="UnselectedStyle"><!--略--></DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedStyle"><!--略--></DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DisabledUnselectedStyle"><!--略--></DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DisabledSelectedStyle"><!--略--></DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <!-- デフォルトの外見 -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UnselectedStyle}"/>
    <!--略-->

    <!-- 条件に応じた外見 -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True"> <!-- ←ここでIsEnabled=Trueも条件に加えたい -->
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedStyle}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

何かご存知の方おられましたら、教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MultiTriggerがつかえます。

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="true" />
            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedStyle}"/>
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。完璧です。